# Balancing a block over two wedges

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

This question is from a gre physics practice test. We have two wedges of mass m and a cube of mass M. These are arranged as shown in the figure [image]

There is no friction between the cube and the wedges, but a coefficient of static friction $\mu \lt 1$ between the wedge and the floor. What is the largest M that can be balanced as shown in the figure so that the wedges do not move?

I have tried using the method of bisection. [image]

So the total normal force on the wedge is

$F_N = \big[m + \frac{M}{2} \big]g$

The force due to the cube ($F_c$) will tend to push the wedge towards the right hand side. $F_c$ will be balanced by the frictional force $F_f = \mu \big[m + \frac{M}{2} \big]g$. So we have

$F_c = \mu \big[m + \frac{M}{2} \big]g$

The confusion that I have is: What is the force due to the block on the wedge ($F_c = ?$) ? It seems to me that since the weight of the block is vertical, it cannot have a horizontal component to push the wedge?

What am I missing here?

Comment: @Qmechanic can you explain why this is "off-topic"?

Answer (score 1):

Each wedge exerts a normal force on the block so, by Newton's 3rd Law, the block must exert an equal and opposite force on each wedge. The vertical component of the normal force from each wedge is $\frac {Mg} 2$ so, by symmetry, the horizontal component of the normal force is ...

Comment: ...... is Mg/2 ?

Comment: @physu Yes, so the horizontal force exerted by the block on each wedge is also $\frac {Mg}{2}$. To avoid the wedges being pushed sideways this horizontal force must be balanced by the frictional force.